# How to structure and architect an angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to develop an angularjs based web app but I am a little bit confused on how should I structure my app. For example I am used on using JSP pages when it come to the front end so for example every different component is a different jsp page let's say a home page, contact page etc. My question is what is the suggested way to do so in angularjs since the angularjs should be a single page web app should I create my content in directives and depending on the flow hide or show other directives or what ? 
Any direction or suggestions for reading will be more than appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend to you reading about Angular Style Guide made by John Papa.

[View Angular Style Guide here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

It's a very helpful guide which provides Angular best practices to deliver a testable, scalable and extensible app.